# How to exit the "Main" status after Prelude(Haskell) loaded a module?

Tags: haskell, load, program-entry-point, haskell-prelude

In Haskell, after using Prelude to load some files

```
Prelude> :l xxxFileName
```

The prompt beomes

```
*Main> xxxx
```

I don't know where the "Main" function come from, as I didn't define any function called "Main". Is this a special status of Haskell's command line environment? How can I exit the "*Main" prompt context and come back to "Prelude>"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

That's a [GHCi convention](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/loading-source-files.html). By default, GHCi will show the name of the module you've loaded. An asterisk (`*`) indicates that you have access on all top-level bindings (definitions that aren't inside of other ones), and not the ones that are exported.

If you didn't specify a module name in the file, GHCi will assume its name is `Main`:

```
-- Example.hs
add x y = x + y
```

```
Prelude> :l Example.hs
*Main>
```

However, if you *do* specify a module name, GHCi will display that one instead:

```
-- ProperModule.hs
module ProperModule where

add x y = x + y
```

```
Prelude> :l ProperModule.hs
*ProperModule>
```

To unload any additional modules, use `:m`, but keep in mind that you cannot use functions from `xxxFileName.hs` anymore. Note that `Prelude` is always loaded, unless you've started GHCi with `-XNoImplicitPrelude`.

Comment: Alternatively, they could `:set prompt` to whatever.  Such as `:set prompt >` to obtain a prompt that is simply `>`.